# Bear minimum Ignite cluster for tests

Tags: ignite

I have a multi-node Ignite cluster working fine on prod. We use the same in our test cases as well with a single node which takes considerable time to spin up. Also, we don't want these to join the cluster if diff test jobs are running on the same machine. Is there any way to spin a minimalistic cluster quickly for tests?

Answer (score 0):

I can start a 3 node cluster on my laptop with no data at startup.
Cluster will come up in 30 seconds or so. Simply open three command
windows and have each start a cluster node. The above would work perfectly for tests. Delete all directories under the work directory after the tests complete for the next run. Done! Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question correctly, the issue is that your test cluster is trying to communicate with the prod one. In that case, you need to properly configure the discovery SPI. For example, you can use a non-overlapping port range. Please take a look at the following page: [Isolated Clusters](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/tcp-ip-discovery#isolated-clusters-on-same-set-of-machines)